# Javascript variables inside twig asset

Tags: javascript, symfony, variables, twig

I want to append images by AJAX in my TWIG template with liipImagineBundle implementation.

---

This is what I want to receive in my javascript:

`<img src="{{ asset('/uploads/xx.jpg' | imagine_filter('liip_filter'))  }}">`

---

Image path is in my **JavaScript variable** name: `value.imgPath`

How can I append it using

`<script>
$('#myId').append('
<img src="{{ asset('/uploads/value.imgPath' |imagine_filter('liip_filter'))  }}" />
');
</script>`

---

**In other words**, How I can use javascript variables inside twig brackets??

Comment: For one, I really think it is a terrible idea :-/ It will open up your app to XSS attacks so you won't know what hit you...

Comment: Or you could call an action of your app, that will return the pre-generated HTML you need. Just call that route with Ajax, Symfony will render the view and return it to your javascript call.

Answer (score 0):

imn't sure but i think this is what you want to do

```
var value = {"imgPath":"img.jpg"};

$('#myId').append("<img src='{{ asset(\"/uploads/"+value.imgPath+"\" |imagine_filter(\"liip_filter\"))  }}' />");
```

Comment: I mean image name is inside variable `value.imgPath` from ajax data. (Like: `var value.imgPath = 'imagename.jpg'`)